# Error Running Jekyll Build: No Repo Name Found

Tags: git, github-actions, jekyll

I am running a Deploy Jekyll site to Pages Action but encountered the following errors:

```
Run bundle exec jekyll build --baseurl "/Site"
Configuration file: /home/runner/work/Site/Site/_config.yml
To use retry middleware with Faraday v2.0+, install `faraday-retry` gem
            Source: /home/runner/work/Site/Site
       Destination: /home/runner/work/Site/Site/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
      Remote Theme: Using theme mmistakes/minimal-mistakes
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
   GitHub Metadata: No GitHub API authentication could be found. Some fields may be missing or have incorrect data.
   GitHub Metadata: Error processing value 'url':
  Liquid Exception: No repo name found. Specify using PAGES_REPO_NWO environment variables, 'repository' in your configuration, or set up an 'origin' git remote pointing to your github.com repository. in /_layouts/default.html
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    No repo name found. Specify using PAGES_REPO_NWO environment variables, 'repository' in your configuration, or set up an 'origin' git remote pointing to your github.com repository.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

It seems I am missing some things in config files:

Here's my `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
authors:
# theme: minimal-mistakes-jekyll
remote_theme: "mmistakes/minimal-mistakes@4.24.0"
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jekyll-seo-tag
  - jekyll-include-cache
  - jekyll-data

# Theme settings

minimal_mistakes_skin: "default"
# Site Settings
```

Here's `.github/workflows/jekyll.yml` (I suspect the issue lies in here)

```
# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

# Sample workflow for building and deploying a Jekyll site to GitHub Pages
name: Deploy Jekyll site to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow only one concurrent deployment, skipping runs queued between the run in-progress and latest queued.
# However, do NOT cancel in-progress runs as we want to allow these production deployments to complete.
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
  # Build job
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@55283cc23133118229fd3f97f9336ee23a179fcf # v1.146.0
        with:
          ruby-version: '3.1' # Not needed with a .ruby-version file
          bundler-cache: true # runs 'bundle install' and caches installed gems automatically
          cache-version: 0 # Increment this number if you need to re-download cached gems
      - name: Setup Pages
        id: pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
      - name: Build with Jekyll
        # Outputs to the './_site' directory by default
        run: bundle exec jekyll build --baseurl "${{ steps.pages.outputs.base_path }}"
        env:
          JEKYLL_ENV: production
      - name: Upload artifact
        # Automatically uploads an artifact from the './_site' directory by default
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1

  # Deployment job
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2
```

'No GitHub API authentication could be found. Some fields may be missing or have incorrect data.'

I have a secret with my personal token?

Edit:

A log of `jekyll build --verbose`:

```
jekyll build --verbose                                                ─╯

/Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:304:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated public_suffix 5.0.1, but your Gemfile requires public_suffix 4.0.7. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
        from /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:25:in `block in setup'
        from /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:165:in `each'
        from /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:165:in `each'
        from /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:24:in `map'
        from /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:24:in `setup'
        from /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/gems/bundler-2.4.13/lib/bundler.rb:162:in `setup'
        from /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:52:in `require_from_bundler'
        from /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/gems/jekyll-4.3.2/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/bin/jekyll:25:in `load'
        from /Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/bin/jekyll:25:in `<main>'
```

My Gemfile:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

# gem “rails”

gem "jekyll"


group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem 'jekyll-feed'
  gem 'jekyll-seo-tag'
  gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
  gem 'jekyll-include-cache'
  gem 'minimal-mistakes-jekyll'
  gem 'jekyll-data'
  end

gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
```

Errors for Build with Jekyll job:

```
Run bundle exec jekyll build --baseurl "/Site"
Configuration file: /home/runner/work/Site/Site/_config.yml
To use retry middleware with Faraday v2.0+, install `faraday-retry` gem
            Source: /home/runner/work/Site/Site
       Destination: /home/runner/work/Site/Site/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
      Remote Theme: Using theme mmistakes/minimal-mistakes
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
   GitHub Metadata: No GitHub API authentication could be found. Some fields may be missing or have incorrect data.
   GitHub Metadata: Error processing value 'url':
  Liquid Exception: No repo name found. Specify using PAGES_REPO_NWO environment variables, 'repository' in your configuration, or set up an 'origin' git remote pointing to your github.com repository. in /_layouts/default.html
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    No repo name found. Specify using PAGES_REPO_NWO environment variables, 'repository' in your configuration, or set up an 'origin' git remote pointing to your github.com repository.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong, can you add `--verbose` to the `jekyll build` command? Maybe additional logs have a clue.

Comment: What does your Gemfile look like?

Comment: Hey @BenjaminW. I added the `-verbose` command logs and Gemfile contents.

Comment: You don't need the github-pages gem if you deploy with your own workflow, and I believe it works against you as it encompasses a ton of gems that you mention explicitly. Also, with a remote theme, you don't need the theme gem. I'd clean up the Gemfile, update the lockfile, and try again. It looks like there's a mess with multiple versions of the same dependencies.

Comment: Did you try `bundle exec jekyll build`?

Comment: `GitHub Metadata: No GitHub API authentication could be found. Some fields may be missing or have incorrect data.` still shows up after `bundle exec jekyll build` i tried `bc jekyll serve` (bc is an alias for bundle exec) and in addition to GitHub Metadata error, there was `bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/Users/kamilszafraniak/.gem/ruby/3.2.2/bin/jekyll)` I will clean the Gemfiles and try again.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. I have a new Gemfile, the GitHub and bundler issues do not appear anymore, however on `bc jekyll serve` I now get:


/Users/kamilszafraniak/.rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/socket.rb:205:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:4000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Comment: That last one means that you already have a process running that listens on port 4000. Use something like described in [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106561/118235) to find out what.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I re-ran the job a few times now, and the same errors keep occurring related to the GitHub config file (see the updated post).